# Diagonal Navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help, was trying to develop a diagonal navigation just like shown in the images below, for something that looks so simple I am spending too much time on it. What I want to happen is that on click of the hamburger menu I need to menu container to reveal from right to left the underlying menu content. I think one of the biggest problem I am having is with the way to handle the navbar change should happen, and also the animation on the menu container, should the menu items be in place while they are being revealed or should it slide from.

To summarise my problems.

1. How do I achieve this design
2. Should I duplicate the navbar section
3. How should the underlaying content be revealed

Any help in this area will be greatly appreciated

[image]
[image]

Below is the code I have tried

```css
.hamburger {
    z-index: 1001;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    #hamburger {
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        top: 18px;
        left: 25px;
    }
    .line {
        width: 24px;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: #fff;
        display: block;
        margin: 6px auto;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    &:after {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        display: block;
      
        background: black;
        content: '';
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, -63%);
    }
}

#hamburger.is-active .line {
    z-index: 1001;
  &:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  &:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

.nav_container {
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    transform: skew(45deg);
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

.nav_container.is-open {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

.navigation-menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    // transform: translateX(150%);
    transform: skew(-45deg);

    > * {
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
  
    &--open {
        transform: translateX(0);
        
        & .navigation-menu__bars {
          background-color: transparent;
          
          &::before,
          &::after {
            top: 0;
          }
        
          &::before {
            transform: rotate(45deg);
          }
    
          &::after {
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
          }
        }
        
        .menu-list__item {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        
        $menu-delay: 1s;
        @for $i from 1 through 12 {
          .menu-list__item:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            transition-delay: $menu-delay;
          }
          $menu-delay: $menu-delay + .25s;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
    <div id="hamburger"><span class="line"></span><span class="line"></span><span class="line"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="nav_container">
    <nav class="navigation-menu js-nav-menu">
        <div class="navbar__menu">
            <ul>
                <li class='title'><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class='title'><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My css is in scss so it won't compile, but it gives an idea of what I have done, any help?

Answer (score -2):

Just use the CSS clip-path rule and you will be able to do whatever your want.
Here's the [Mozila documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), and here you got a [clip path generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Peace

Comment: The problem with clip path is that it does not work on IE

Comment: Next time precise the compatibility needs, most people use Chrome, firefox or Safari.